# Why button generated using javascript is not working properly?

Tags: javascript

I am creating 3 text boxes and a button using javascript, then adding a listener to the button which then gets the value of the 3 textboxes and returns the largest number.

This is the code I am using to generate text boxes:

```
var elementID = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for(i=0; i<elementID.length; i++) {
    var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    inputElement.setAttribute('id', elementID[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(inputElement);
}
```

I tried adding the boxes directly in HTML but it returns the same wrong result.

Here is the code for adding button and attaching an event listener:

```
var eventHandler = function(event) {
    var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var c = document.getElementById('c').value;

    alert(largestNumber(a, b, c));
};

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('id', 'button');
button.textContent = "Submit";
document.body.appendChild(button);
button.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
```

And this is the code I use to calculate the largest number:

```
var largestNumber = function(a, b, c) {
    return (((a>b) ?a:b) > c) ? (a>b?a:b):c;
};
```

At first I thought this might be a problem with the above code so I tried using the good old `if else` but still it didn't work.

The problem is that it returns the wrong number, for example - if I type 63 in the first box, 210 in second and 57 in third, it will return 63 as the largest number.

Finally here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prsLocjw/2/).

Comment: Please modify your question title so that it fits the problem. Your problem is not about button or its event. It's about your function calculating the largest number. This should come in the title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers are being compared as string values. Try converting them to numbers first using the `parseInt` function:

```
var eventHandler = function(event) {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('b').value);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('c').value);

    alert(largestNumber(a, b, c));
};
```

```js
var largestNumber = function(a, b, c) {
  return (((a > b) ? a : b) > c) ? (a > b ? a : b) : c;
};

var elements = [{
  id: 'a',
  val: 63
}, {
  id: 'b',
  val: 210
}, {
  id: 'c',
  val: 57
}];
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
  inputElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  inputElement.setAttribute('id', elements[i].id);
  inputElement.value = elements[i].val;
  document.body.appendChild(inputElement);
}

var eventHandler = function(event) {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('b').value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('c').value);

  console.log(largestNumber(a, b, c));
};

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('id', 'button');
button.textContent = "Submit";
document.body.appendChild(button);
button.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your `largestNumber` function to:

```
var largestNumber = function() {
    return Math.max.apply(null, arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.Max

```
var largestNumber = function(a, b, c) {
    var arr = [a, b, c];
    return Math.max(...arr);
};
```

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prsLocjw/5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your values are **NOT** converted to numbers. And Javascript compares the strings which leads to unexpected results you're seeing. This problem could be solved either by using `Math.max()` or `Math.max.apply()` (Check [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)) because `Math.max()` function tries to convert its arguments to numbers (see **CD..**'s answer) or by explicit conversion of the values to numbers (e.g., by `parseInt` but maybe your numbers are not integers e.g, 1.3 and 1.5 then you could use `Number()` function) as proposed by **Moishe**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the return type of `value` is `string` and expected type of your `largestNumber` function is `number`.
When you do string comparison it compares the `UTF-16` code unit value of each character. In this case first number is `63` and second number is `210`. Because `'6' > '2'`, your function always returns `63`.

You need to change your function call to: `alert(largestNumber(Number(a), Number(b), Number(c)));`.

Besides the bug, you are better off using `static` built-in `Math.max` function instead of writing your own implementation. It will:
a) simplify your code, b) will be more reliable, performant, and readable,  and c) will future-proof it in case you want to compare more than 3 numbers.

Comment: Actually, since JavaScript strings are UTF-16 encoded Unicode codepoints, it compares the UTF-16 code units, not the "ASCII values". So, as you say, "63" > "210" because '6' > '2' ('\u0036' > '\u0032').

Answer (score -1):

kindly use this
alert(largestNumber(parseInt(a), parseInt(b), parseInt(c)));

Comment: That won't change anything. JS does automatic type conversion.

Comment: @AndrewL. My logic is right, JS does NOT do automatic type conversion.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria when test equality with == of course it does. === does not.

Comment: @AndrewL. Have a look at Moishe's answer, that works.

Comment: @AndrewL. You are right that JS does automatic conversion with `==`, but only when the two operands have different types. If both are of the same type (string in the OP's code), then no conversion is done. Conversion to what?

Comment: @RacilHilan Very true.